# Swift Reducing an array of Tuples in

Tags: swift

Is there a way in which I can call the reduce function on an array of tuples to find a max value?

For example

```
struct Gate{

    var maxedOpenGates = 1

    var GatesOpen : [(openOrdered : Int, gateNum : Int )] = []

    init(defaultSelected : Int = 0){

        GatesOpen.append(openOrdered : 1, gateNum : defaultSelected)
    }

    private func manipulateGates(gates : [SegmentButton]){
        for i in GatesOpen{
            gates[i.gateNum].toggleSelected()
        }

    }

    mutating func openGate(index : Int, buttons : [SegmentButton]){

        if GatesOpen.count < maxedOpenGates{
            GatesOpen.append(  openOrdered: GatesOpen.count , gateNum: index)

        }else{
         //////Finding the gate that was Opened the longest////
            let lastGate = GatesOpen.reduce(Int.min,{ max($0,$1) })

        }
        manipulateGates(buttons)
    }
}
```

where a I am trying to reduce based on **openOrdered**

```
 let lastGate = GatesOpen.reduce(Int.min,{ max($0,$1) })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can reduce an array of tuples like any other array.
The arguments of the combine function are elements of the array, in your
case "gate tuples". And if the result of reducing the array should also be a gate tuple then the initial element and the result of the combine function
must also be of that type:

```
let lastGate = gatesOpen.reduce(gatesOpen[0]) {
        $0.openOrdered < $1.openOrdered ? $1 : $0
}
```

Of course the array must have at least one element for this to work.
To avoid the unnecessary comparison of `gatesOpen[0]` with itself
you can change it to (edited after @Airspeed's comment):

```
let lastGate = dropFirst(gatesOpen).reduce(gatesOpen[0]) {
    $0.openOrdered < $1.openOrdered ? $1 : $0
}
```

Comment: I find `dropFirst(gatesOpen)` is a bit nicer than the manual slicing operation.  If you want to account for the empty array possibility with an optional, you can use `first.map` to return a `nil` if the array’s empty: `let lastGate = gatesOpen.first.map { fst in
                dropFirst(gatesOpen).reduce(fst) {
                    $0.openOrdered < $1.openOrdered ? $1 : $0
                }
            }`

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: Good idea with dropFirst. – I had also thought about handling an empty array (your suggestion is very elegant!), but from the given code it seemed to me that there is at least one "gate", so I did not want to complicate things. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Very nice! The explanation above, complemented with the examples greatly helps my understanding of the reduce function and other functions that mimic such design.

Answer (score 3):

Using closure with reduce function,

```
 //////Finding the gate that was Opened the longest////
let intitalValue = (Int.min,Int.min)
let lastGate: (openOrdered: Int, gateNum: Int) = GatesOpen.reduce(intitalValue){
         (longestOpenGate: (openOrdered: Int, gateNum: Int), gate) in
          if(longestOpenGate.openOrdered < gate.openOrdered) {
                  return gate;
          } else {
                  return longestOpenGate;
          }

}
let lastGateNumber = lastGate.gateNum;
```

Or,

```
let lastGate: (openOrdered: Int, gateNum: Int) = GatesOpen.reduce(intitalValue){
   $0.openOrdered < $1.openOrdered ? $1 : $0
}
let lastGateNumber = lastGate.gateNum;
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Reducing an array of Tuples to an array:

```
let arr:[Int] = [(0,""),(1,"")].reduce([]) { $0 + [$1.0] }//Ouput:[0, 1]
```

Comment: Can you show how to use aliases in place of the `$0` / `$1` ?

Comment: @javadba `{ accumulator, element in ... }`

Comment: Thx. what does the `.0` mean in `$1.0` ?

Comment: 0$, 1$ means first and second closure element, .0 and .1 means first and second item in the closure element. This is standard swift syntax tho. ✌️